# small RNA bioanalyzer traces showing miRNA enrichment for sRNA-seq

Tags: small-rnaseq

I am bioinformatician trying to support some small RNA-seq experiments. All bioanalyzer traces that I have seen for RNA at the small RNA range show at peak at 22. But probably it depends on the protocol for the RNA purification (in this case only experience with RNeasy Qiagen).

I would like to know if some of you have some examples/experience of good bioanalyzer results after RNA purification that have been sequenced and got a big percentage of miRNA detected.

Currently I have a example where there is a broad peak at 25 and in some cases a small peak at 22. After sequencing there is almost not data. So at some point we lost the data. Trying to figure out if the bioanalyzer was good at that point, or already was something wrong.

thanks.